# React useState() array not updating inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, fetch, tabulator

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import 'react-tabulator/lib/styles.css';
import { ReactTabulator } from 'react-tabulator'

export default function Project() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

    
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const projectListUri = '/api/projects';
    // const apiPath = process.env.REACT_SERVER_HOST + projectListUri;
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/projects")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data); // line 16
                setProjects(data);
                console.log(projects); //line 18
                setLoading(false);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <ReactTabulator
                    data={projects}
                    autoColumns={true}
                    layout={"fitColumns"}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );



}
```

Above is my code I am running in my application. I am fetching data from my backend server. The fetch data goes fine. I can see data correctly logged on line 16. But line 18 always show an empty array. And hence Tabulator library gives `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice').` The isLoading constant updates correctly.

I have tried `setProjects(...data); setProjects([data]); setProjects(...projects, ...data);` Neither works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: @AndyRay it does kind of. I understand now that useState is async. How do I fix this but?

Comment: @AnmolGarg
What's your purpose?
Why do you need the project immediately after setting up the state?
Your current code should render the table correctly.
Initially your data would be an empty array but immediately fetching the data successfully, you current code should work.

Comment: @JahedulHoque my current code doesn't work. Gives `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice').` on rendering. This error is coming from tabulator.js

Comment: @AnmolGarg
Then you should also share the tabulator.js code. It seems the issue is there.

Comment: It seems likely your API data does not match the format required by `ReactTabulator`. You're confused abut your logging as shown in the duplicate question linked. I would double check your API response and make sure it's the format that `react-tabulator` expects.

Comment: I tried in one of their sandboxes and looks like autoColumns isn't really working, so I'd suggest you to define the columns property and retry. I don't think your fetch call is the problem.

Comment: Thankyou Andy, Jahdeul and Silviu. The problem was indeed the tabulator library autocolumn. Thanks!

Comment: @AnmolGarg whenever you call setProject() to update state you will never get updated value of that state in next line because of asynchronous state updation...also use setProjects([...data]) like this

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you can use the another useEffect hook to observe changes in the projects state and perform actions accordingly.
Here's the updated code  :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import 'react-tabulator/lib/styles.css';
import { ReactTabulator } from 'react-tabulator';

export default function Project() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const projectListUri = '/api/projects';

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/projects")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setProjects(data);
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, []);

//here's the modified code
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(projects);
    }, [projects]); 

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <ReactTabulator
                    data={projects}
                    autoColumns={true}
                    layout={"fitColumns"}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```